# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 18 Incorrect syntax near ','

Tags: sql-server

Is doesn't seem to like the first comma after `SUM(c.[chargeable weight])`. Do you guys can identify why? I genuinely can't understand the reason why it is doing this.

```
    Select  
 (SUM(c.[Chargeable Weight]), MAX (ts.systemstamp), mm.MovementRef
                                FROM      dbo.whsConsignment wc
                                                   INNER JOIN dbo.cgtConsignment c ON c.[Consignment Reference] = wc.ConsignmentReference
                                                   INNER JOIN dbo.tsAdditionalColInfo ts on ts.[ConsignmentReference]= wc.ConsignmentReference
                                                    inner join dbo.movConLink m on m.ConsignmentReference = c.[Consignment Reference]
                                                   inner join dbo.movMovement mm on mm.MovementID = m.MovementID
                                                                                                            --AND wc.whsHeaderID = wh.WhsHeaderID
                                                                                                            AND wc.StatusCode = 'NL'
                                                                                                            AND c.[Service Type] = 'C'
                                                                                                            --AND ts.SlackNoSlack like 'No Slack - Must Load%' 
                                                                                                            --and ts.SLackNoSLack like 'No Slack - Tripped%'
                                                                                                            and ts.scheduledescription = 'No Slack - Tripped'
                                                                                                            group by mm.MovementRef) as chargeableweight
                                                                                                            --and ts.systemstamp = max (ts.systemstamp)
 Into #2chargns
```

Comment: Where is the closing bracket for the one that starts before `SUM`?

Comment: Not sure if it fits the error message, but if you `select into` every attribute must have a name. Currently your aggregated columns don't have a name.

Comment: Thank you very much -  your suggestions helped me to solve the problem!

Answer (score 1):

You missed the `SELECT` within the brackets

```
   SELECT * FROM
 (SELECT SUM(c.[Chargeable Weight]) AS Sum, MAX (ts.systemstamp) AS Max, mm.MovementRef
                                FROM      dbo.whsConsignment wc
                                                   INNER JOIN dbo.cgtConsignment c ON c.[Consignment Reference] = wc.ConsignmentReference
                                                   INNER JOIN dbo.tsAdditionalColInfo ts on ts.[ConsignmentReference]= wc.ConsignmentReference
                                                    inner join dbo.movConLink m on m.ConsignmentReference = c.[Consignment Reference]
                                                   inner join dbo.movMovement mm on mm.MovementID = m.MovementID
                                                                                                            --AND wc.whsHeaderID = wh.WhsHeaderID
                                                                                                            AND wc.StatusCode = 'NL'
                                                                                                            AND c.[Service Type] = 'C'
                                                                                                            --AND ts.SlackNoSlack like 'No Slack - Must Load%' 
                                                                                                            --and ts.SLackNoSLack like 'No Slack - Tripped%'
                                                                                                            and ts.scheduledescription = 'No Slack - Tripped'
                                                                                                            group by mm.MovementRef) as chargeableweight
                                                                                                            --and ts.systemstamp = max (ts.systemstamp)
 Into #2chargns
```

Comment: Wouldn't solve the problem - `Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks have updated the query :)